# Angular/Ionic FormGroup, FormArray, FormBuilder... I'm lost

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, formbuilder, formarray

Use case:  This is an inventory update page for a coffee shop.

[image]

An inventory item is defined like this:

```
interface InventoryData {
  category: string;
  current: number;
  id: string;
  name: string;
  par: number;
  units: string;
  previous?: string;
  supplier: string;
  notes?: string;
}
```

On this page, I'm only manipulating the `current` level and the `notes?` for each item.

At the bottom of the form, I have an `ion-textarea` that is a space for the associates to write anything that the managers should know.

[image]

So the structure of the page is

```
HEADER
   SECTION HEADERS ENTERED AUTOMATICALLY ON CHANGE OF CATEGORY

      ITEM[0]                                  <-+
          [ITEM DETAILS]                         |
          [INPUT CURRENT QUANTITY]               |
          [INPUT NOTES]                          |--- Array of similar items with
      ITEM[1]...                                 |    inputs for quantity and notes
      ITEM[2]...                                 |    for each
                                                 |
      ITEM[n]                                  <-+

  GENERAL NOTES SECTION                <---- not part of an item... overall info.

FOOTER
```

I have tried setting up the page has having two separate forms, one for the inventory items and one for the general notes at the end.  Something like this:

```
  inventoryForm = this.fb.group({
    items: this.fb.array([]),
  });

  notesForm = this.nb.group({
    notes: [''],
  });
```

And I have tried setting it up as a single form that has the array items plus one additional form field for the general notes.

But it all seems very messy.

**So I'm hoping to learn how experienced people would do this.**  This is more of a strategy question than a coding question, but I'd be thrilled with advice from either direction.

Comment: This is a very opinionated question... but my two cents. I would have just one form and I don't feel like it is messy. Usually backend wants the data in a certain way and that is how we then structure the forms, at least as far as possible, so that when form is submitted, it's ideal if it can be sent as is to the backend.

Answer (score 2):

Usually when in such a conflicting state I ask myself:

1. Does the data go back in a single API? (No means heavily lean towards two form)
2. Does updating value in one can impact (validate) the other form.
   (Yes heavily lean towards a single form, No means lean towards two form)
3. Is component reusability making an impact. (you can also create reusable form components in angular)

In your case, if both from are submitted together with a single button in a single API then it should be a single form.

It might look messy if you are writing a lot of code in a single component. You can always divide the code as much as possible.

```
 inventoryForm = this.fb.group({
    items: this.fb.array([]),
    notes: [''],
  });
```

Just an observation:
Your note area looks more like a comment area.